# Two reflective surfaces facing each other in openGL

Tags: opengl, cubemap

How do I render 2 reflective surfaces, Example a mirror, face each other? To render a single surface I would use a cube map by rendering from the object on six directions.

But to render 2 surfaces it is becoming a paradox on which one to render first! Can anyone gimme a spark?

https://learnopengl.com/#!Advanced-OpenGL/Cubemaps

I used this tutorial

Answer (score 3):

There aren't many options for this:

1. Use the previous frame's rendering result in a feed-back loop, initialize with black, or transparent, or a fake reflection texture
2. Same as 1 but render a few extra times quickly within 1 frame to reduce reflection lag
3. Use pure ray-tracing with a limit on ray bounces

Number 3 is impractical in most situations.

Comment: Oh..anyway. how ue4 accomplish it?

Comment: You'll have to create a new question for this.

Comment: @YashwanthCB Surely not 3, so it must be 1 or 2. The difference is not that big.